# explain get chainlink VRF fee cost

Tags: gas-price, chainlink, price, vrf, data-feeds

Hi can somebody explain to me every variable and operator of this function

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to narrow down what parts you have specific questions about. Explaining a function is outside the scope of StackExchange. Which specific part are you trying to understand?

https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I just don't understand what 1e12 and 1e18 stand for in this function is it decimals of link or eth ?

Comment: 1e12 and 1e18 are used to calculate the amount of link

1 link / 1e6 = 1e18 juels / 1e6 = 1e12 juels

You can see the full calculation in the contract here that lays out why 1e12 and 1e18 are used. 
https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/fd91cc7346551ada741a76bac86a8563b3c679bc/contracts/src/v0.8/dev/VRFCoordinatorV2.sol#L582